# invalid operation on glEnd without cause?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been working on a GL program for some time now and suddenly it began to give errors.
After trying to resolve these for a while I wrote a short test program that generates the same behavior:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

#define CHECK_GL_ERR() printError(__LINE__)

void printError(int line)
{
        GLenum err = glGetError();
        if(err != GL_NO_ERROR)
        {
                std::cerr << "GL error on line " << line << ": " << gluErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        }
}

void displayFunc()
{
        CHECK_GL_ERR();
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        CHECK_GL_ERR();
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        CHECK_GL_ERR();
        glEnd();
        CHECK_GL_ERR(); //line 23
        exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
        glutCreateWindow("Test");

        glutDisplayFunc(displayFunc);

        glutMainLoop();
}
```

When I run this program it gives the output:

```
GL error on line 23: invalid operation
```

So it seems that `glEnd();` causes the error.
The docs say:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glEnd is executed without being
>               preceded by a glBegin.

Which is not the case in my code. So does anyone see, why this code gives an error message?

PS: Of course I know that glBegin/End has been deprecated/removed for a long time but it is very convenient to hack together some small amounts of code. Also the program worked without errors until GL decided to be grumpy.

**EDIT**

I just did a trace with glslDevil which gave:

```
W! Program Start
|  glXQueryExtension(0x1ab03f0, (nil), (nil))
|  glXChooseFBConfig(0x1ab03f0, 0, 0x7fffb8fcf8b0, 0x7fffb8fcf8a4)
|  glXGetVisualFromFBConfig(0x1ab03f0, 0x111)
|  glXGetProcAddressARB(0x7f93c37526e5)
|  glXCreateNewContext(0x1ab03f0, 0x111, 32788, (nil), 1)
|  glXIsDirect(0x1ab03f0, 0x1ac8de8)
|  glXMakeContextCurrent(0x1ab03f0, 123731970, 123731970, 0x1ac8de8)
|  glXMakeContextCurrent(0x1ab03f0, 123731970, 123731970, 0x1ac8de8)
|  glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT)
|  glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT)
|  glXMakeContextCurrent(0x1ab03f0, 123731970, 123731970, 0x1ac8de8)
|  glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300)
|  glXMakeContextCurrent(0x1ab03f0, 123731970, 123731970, 0x1ac8de8)
|  glXMakeContextCurrent(0x1ab03f0, 123731970, 123731970, 0x1ac8de8)
|  glGetError()
|  glBegin(GL_POINTS)
|  glGetError()
|  glVertex3f(0,000000, 0,000000, 0,000000)
|  glGetError()
|  glEnd()
W! OpenGL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION detected
|  glGetError()
|  glXMakeContextCurrent(0x1ab03f0, 123731970, 123731970, 0x1ac8de8)
|  glXDestroyContext(0x1ab03f0, 0x1ac8de8)
E! Child process exited
W! Program termination forced!
```

Comment: Cleaning and then rebuilding the project could probably resolve this kind of a "surprise" problem..

Comment: As you can see this short example fully exposes the error and I built it from scratch to have a demo. But just for the sake of completeness: I deleted the binaries and recompiled and the error stays where it is.

Comment: Error confirmed on Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Which graphics driver/card do you use? I run a GTX 560, driver version 304.64 on openSUSE 12.2 x64.

Comment: Maybe a recent driver/system update has decided to be a bit more forceful about the deprecation of `glBegin/glEnd`?

Comment: @IronMensan: I did no updates at the time the error occured, so it would be very strange. But then again it is very strange that the error occurs in the first place.

Comment: @Nobody Sorry, I have no clue. I just compiled your example and ran it. I can't contribute anything more. My system is a five year old computer with X11 and a Nvidia chipset (lspci says GeForce 7050 PV / nForce 630a).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some testing, I found your program have two simple issues:

1. You must not use glGetError inside a glBegin/glEnd block. The [API](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGetError.xml) is strict about that. But the error only happens **after** glEnd. If you read the API, you'll find that the error might propagate: it only happens after the glEnd.
2. A segmentation fault occurs when you use exit(0) **inside** the display function(that only happens with the Intel driver.) That happens because the GL context hasn't been freed yet, and a driver bug comes along. So you should avoid exit inside the display function.

Comment: Wow I fooled myself with the macro and forgot that glGetError is a GL call itself. Thanks for the research on that. About point 2 I do not use the Intel driver and the exit was only added to prevent multiple execution, after all the program does nothing more at this point.